# Sketch: How to best sync design elements between iOS and Android Wireframe?

Tags: sketch-app, mobile, android, ios, wireframing

I'm looking for some input on your best practices/workflows for creating app wireframes for both iOS and Android.

I'm working on a project now that needs quite high fidelity wireframes for an app we are creating, both for Android and iOS. The problem is how do I best share styles between the two files? If I create symbols of for instance a table, the width of the table won't match, since iOS and Android differs. So I have to detatch the element from the symbol. The problem is now if I want to change a color for instance, I will have to rememeber to update it in both versions. Font/typography settings will also differ between these two.

How can I structure my workflow when developing for both platforms, to reduce duplication of work?

Since I'm using Google Drive sync for Invision, the Android/iOS wireframes will have to be in seperate files as well. :/

Comment: In terms of best practice, "high fidelity wireframe" isn't a thing.

Answer (score 1):

### Styles before symbols

Your best bet is to use styles rather than symbols for most layout units. Where the is a good reason to use a symbol (eg global nav), the component items of that symbol should use a style that is synced across files.

### Plug-ins fill in the gaps

For the synchronization, I'll have to do some research and get back to you. There is a plug-in that allows you to manage certain style properties in a Google Sheet. You could reference each file to the same sheet. As with most needs in Sketch, there are a few Plug-ins you might want to try. Do some GitHub sleuthing and experiment.

### Bottom line

You'll just have to be disciplined. Sketch hasn't yet tackled cross-ffile synchronization.